# React Context is not updating and returning initial value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to provide Web3Context.Provider value but it's not updating.

```
//Web3Context.js
import React from "react";
const Web3Context = React.createContext();
export default Web3Context;
```

```
//useWeb3.js
import { useContext } from "react";
import Web3Context from "./Web3Context";
export function useWeb3() {
  return useContext(Web3Context);
}
```

```
//web3hook.js
export function useDefaultAccount() {
  const web3 = useWeb3(); //Undefined, this should be equal to the value provide to Web3Context.Provider

// logic 
}
```

I have provided value to Context in App.js file

```
//App.js
function App() {

  const { web3 } = useWeb3Provider();
  const account = useDefaultAccount(); //Undefined because web3 in web3hook.js is undefined
  return (
    <Web3Context.Provider value={web3}>
 </Web3Context.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem (for instance, what is `useWeb3Provider`? or if it's not relevant, remove it from the code). To really help us help you, make it a **runnable** MRE by using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX and hooks (you have to update the version of React, instructions in the link); [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Do you ```return``` that?

Comment: You might have misunderstood the core concept of context. You can use context value in the components which are the child of the contextProvider. In your case to use the Web3Context you have to access the context value inside any child of the `Web3Context.Provider`

Answer (score 2):

You can use context value in the components which are the child of the contextProvider.

you have to access the context value inside any child of the Web3Context.Provider

```
function Component() {
    const account = useDefaultAccount();
    // do something
}
function App() {
    const { web3 } = useWeb3Provider();
    return (
        <Web3Context.Provider value={web3}>
            <Component />
        </Web3Context.Provider>
    );
}
```